# Logic Apps(event hub to adls)

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-logic-apps, azure-backup-vault

I'm currently working a gig to build a logic app for one of our main clients.

They(A) currently have Azure Backup data streaming into an event hub. On the directory is a logic app that's collecting the data from A - Event hub.

They have asked us to move the data from the event hub in the logic app to a ADLS store. Anyone know what types of connectors to use within the logic app to move data from event hub to data lake ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyone know what types of connectors to use within the logic app to move data from event hub to data lake ?

We could use the Eventhub trigger and Datalake action to do that in the logic app. For more information please refer to the screenshot. But we also could [Use Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 to capture data from Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-archive-eventhub-capture) directly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I got the data sorted :-)